# Function calls are not supported in decorators (Angular 8)

Tags: angular

I've upgraded to `Angular 8.0.0-beta.3` (yeah I know its beta), but for some reason my app will no longer compile with AOT. It does work perfectly fine otherwise.

The problem with these errors is that they are exactly as I post them below, there are no further indication as to what path / file is causing the issue. It only lists `Component`, `Injectable` or `Directive`.

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'NgModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Component'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Directive'
```

Any ideas why this might be happening or a way of how I could find more detailed information?